# Div tag shape not showing

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>HTML</title>
  
  <!-- HTML -->
  

  <!-- Custom Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="face"></div>
    <div class="eyeleft"></div>
    <div class="eyeright"></div>
    <div class="smile"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Project -->
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to create a round face using the following css code and it should be linked to the div tag.

```
.face {
  color: #ffe9d1;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  border-width: 100px, 100px, 100px, 100px;
  border-radius: 50px, 50px, 50px, 50px;
}
```

There arent any more details to include but perhaps this might do.

Please explain why it's not showing

Comment: no comma inside the properties, only space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you've used for specifying `border-width` and `border-radius` is incorrect.

You must instead use this:

```css
.face {
  color: #ffe9d1;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px; /* Notice this */
  border: 100px red solid; /* Notice this */
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="face"></div>
    <div class="eyeleft"></div>
    <div class="eyeright"></div>
    <div class="smile"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the syntax for `border-width` and `border-radius` indeed accepts 4 values, so this is not the problem.

But: the border property needs 3 parameters in CSS: `border-width`, `border-style`, and `border-color`. And here `border-style` was missing. For example, set it to "solid". If you leave it undefined, it will default to "none", which is not visible.
Adapted CSS which gives the result ->

```
.face {
  color: #ffe9d1;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 100px, 100px, 100px, 100px;
  border-radius: 50px, 50px, 50px, 50px;
}
```

Comment: Addendum: You want to add a height and width property as well to give the face container room for displayal, otherwise it will not show, so you should add in your css the 2 properties for example with width: 200px; height: 200px;

Comment: Thank you for your help. its greatly appreciated.